# Переклад слова "Соковыжималка" українською, або його альтернатива

Tags: переклад, вибір-слова, from-russian

Багато словників пропонують перекласти слово просто транслітерацією, замінивши `Ы` на `И`.

Існує так само варіант перекладу — *сокоробка*. Але цей варіант так само можна поставити під сумнів, бо *сокоробка* не передасть суті процесу даного пристрою, робити сік можна і методом випарювання, наприклад.

*Вичавлювати* українською — *витискати*, яке в даному випадку втрачає своє справжнє значення.

Чи можливий альтернативний переклад терміна *соковичавниця*? І чи доречно буде вживання слова *вичавлювати* до суті процесу даного пристрою?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> <sup>[Російсько-український народний сучасний словник 2009](//r2u.org.ua/html/announcement.html)</sup>
>   [Соковыжималка](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=10&highlight=on) — соковидавлювач, соковичавлювач, [соковичавниця](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F/), сокодавилка.

---

> <sup>[Вікіпедія](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87)</sup>
>   Соковитискач, сокочавилка

---

Не дуже по темі, але видно якими дієсловами *дістають* сік.

> <sup>[Фразеологічний словник української мови](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53409/361261.html)</sup>
>   **видавлювати** (**вижимати**, **витягати** і т. ін.) / **ви[давити](/a/3904/585)** (**вижати**, **витягнути** і т. ін.) **(усі) соки** з кого.
>
> 1. Нещадно експлуатувати, визискувати кого-небудь. *(Шкереберть:) Я пускав з торбою вдів і сиріт, я **видавлював усі соки** з робітників, робив їх рабами своїми* [(Марко Кропивницький)](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%9B%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%87); ***Витягав соки*** пан Кшивокольський із своїх хлопів. Він хотів би, аби вони й не спали, і не їли, а все би робили, робили [(Гнат Хоткевич)](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87_%D0%93%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82_%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87); *Пришельці-колонізатори гидкі, а хіба менш гидкі вислужники їхні, холуї? Запроданці, що сіли на тих уранах і **вичавлюють соки** з своїх одноплемінців* [(Олесь Гончар)](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%80_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C_%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87); ***Вижмуть*** підприємці з таких, як він, **соки**, .. награбують доларів, заюшених кровʼю, а їх, трудівників, згодом виженуть на вулицю [(Іван Цюпа)](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D1%8E%D0%BF%D0%B0_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%90%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87).
> 2. Дуже знесилювати, виснажувати кого-небудь важкою роботою. *Колись за Франца-Йосифа та польського панства бідак все життя пнувся на свою хатину, **витягав** з себе **соки** й з нової хати поганяв до ями* [(Степан Чорнобривець)](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C_%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%90%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87).

Comment: але усталитись має одне слово, хіба ні? Яке?

Comment: Мабуть не скоро усталиться. Хоча, на мою думку, „вичавлювати сік“  найпитоміший варіант. Може варто трохи коротше - сокочавка.

Answer (score 4):

«Українсько-англійський, англо-український словник. 120 000 слів» Олесі Сидоренко, Володимира Тесленка, Анни Заворони, Івана Сидоренка (2015, Книжковий Клуб «Клуб Сімейного Дозвілля», Харків, ISBN 978-966-14-9349-9, 640 с.), що начебто рекомендований кафедрою сучасної української мови Інституту філології Київського національного університету ім. Тараса Шевченка (принаймні, так написано на його обкладинці) наводить варіант «**[сокодавильниця](//books.google.com/books?id=686fCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA249&dq=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F)**»:

> juicer [ˈdʒu:sə] *n* сокодавильниця

Answer (score 1):

Залежить від того в якому регіоні живуть, які традиції, які схильності до творення нових слів.

Я ось придумав: сокоробка,  сокодавка, давилка, соковачка.

Це велика поблема з підбором слів. Треба не боятись і творити нові. Трохи практики, і все вийде. Дивитись в словники теж треба, це допоможе знайти вже існуюче слово.

Мова — це матеріал, яким треба вміти користуватись.

Comment: У нас кажуть *хлібороб*, *бракороб* тощо. Тому, почувши *сокоробка*, я б спочатку подумав про жінку, яка робить сік, а не про приладдя для цього.

Comment: @Yola, ну, а з іншого боку — по-моєму, це очікувано, що в умовах науково-технічного поступу форми, які раніше позначали професії, частково переходять на прилади (_коректор_, _навігатор_ тощо).

Comment: @Sasha ууу.. я про це не подумав, а це цікаво. Дякую!