# Чи правильно писати "Готуйте в сокодавильниці"?

Tags: вживання-слів

Російський-український народний сучасний словник 2009—

> ***[Соковыжималка](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)*** — *соковидавлювач, соковичавлювач, соковичавниця, сокодавилка.*

СУМ-11 має визначення

> ***[Соковижималка](http://sum.in.ua/s/sokovyzhymalka)***  ***и, жін.*** *Пристрій для вичавлювання соку з фруктів, ягід і овочів.*

У жодному з цих джерел слова *сокодавильниця* не знайшла.

***Чи правильно писати „Готуйте в сокодавильниці“?*** [image]

На сайті є запитання [Переклад слова “Соковыжималка” українською, або його альтернатива](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/2565/), але там слово *сокодавильниця* не згадується.

Answer (score 2):

Для слова «[соковижима́лка](http://sum.in.ua/s/sokovyzhymalka)» (яке має статтю в «Словнику української мови» в 11 томах, однак багатьма сприймається як росіянізм) існує багато альтернатив, з яких однак жодна ще, здається, не встигла остаточно закріпитися — тому, якому з варіантів надавати перевагу, мені здається, на даний момент є радше справою особистих вподобань.

Варіант «**сокодавильниця**» [наводить](//books.google.com/books?id=686fCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA249&dq=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F) зокрема «Українсько-англійський, англо-український словник. 120 000 слів» Олесі Сидоренко, Володимира Тесленка, Анни Заворони, Івана Сидоренка (2015, Книжковий Клуб «Клуб Сімейного Дозвілля», Харків, ISBN 978-966-14-9349-9, 640 с.), що начебто рекомендований кафедрою сучасної української мови Інституту філології Київського національного університету ім. Тараса Шевченка (принаймні, так написано на його обкладинці):

> juicer [ˈdʒu:sə] *n* сокодавильниця